# Is Eid-e-Milad-ul-Nabi (P.B.U.H) allowed or prohibited?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, eid

Milad-ul-Nabi (P.B.U.H) is being celebrated in various parts of Muslim countries every year.

1. Is it proved from Quran and Sunnat-e-Rasool (P.B.U.H)?
2. Does Sahaba celebrated it?
3. If someone don't attends this. Should he be called a "Satan(Iblees)"?

Comment: Similar question: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1214/is-celebrating-the-mawlid-day-halal-or-haram

Comment: https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/1527202143/ is a great read for answering this question. In short, different sects will give you different answers. As a sunni, I firmly believe that it is a good innovation that one should act upon.

Comment: The notion of "good innovation" is direct opposition of hadith of Prophet of Allaah   ﷺ which says "every innovation is misguidance"

ref https://sunnah.com/nawawi40:28

Comment: As-written, this is just attracting Truth answers, which end up being more confusing than helpful. We as a site are not here to prove which interpretation of Islam is more correct than any other, questions need to focus on objective answerable facts, not opinions.

Answer (score 1):

Just remember 12th Rabi-Ul-Awal is the day when Muhammad(PBUH) also passed away. If you want to recite Durud for him, you can do it, that's about it. But just don't overdo things, its not  permissible in Shaariah.

Answer (score 0):

1- No , it's not proved from the Quran nor from Sunna

2- No , Al Sahaba did't celebrate the day , also they make Alhijra day the start day of year not the day of birth of the prophet

3- It's not prohibited to celebrate in general But it's been prohibited if there was prohibited actions in it , like inviting men and women to the same place so that they may see and talk to each other , or have Music,Dancing(maybe),Women Singing .. and so on

finally no body should been called "Satan" nor "Iblees" for any wrong thing he did ,instead he should been told about his wrong kindly , and that he should ask Allah to forgive him , and should decide sincerely that he will not repeat what he did (All this between him and his God , no place for any body between him and Allah to say for e.g you will not be blessed ever )

Beside the question
when make the celebrate a day to remember the prophet and to forget him all other days , of course the Prophet will not be happy of us when we celebrate his day !

We Should following Al Sunna as Allah orders us , then we will see that celebrating is not that Important thing to do as the Religion is not Appearances and trappings,it's what you really are from inside , and how you're following Rasulallah's steps .

Peace Be Upon him

Answer (score 0):

Celebrating a birthday of Prophet PBUH is not matter of fiqah or  islamic law it is actually a cultural activity. As Islam is global religion and provides complete code of life for whole mankind and emphasized on principles of shariah. It gives broader principles of Haram(anti Islamic)and Halal (pro islamic) which are equally govern on each activity or gathering. 
So each type of activity having anti Islamic segment will be called Haram. In the case of celebrating birthday of Prophet PBUH it is Halal if it's segments are within the parameters of sharia. I think this day is the most precious day in the history of mankind when REHMAT UL LIL ALAMEEN came for benefits of all living world's. So in this day Muslims thanks Allah by arranging mahafils in which HAMAD & NAATS are recited. Likewise if we see this issue from the life of Prophet PBUH than a lot of other cultural activities like celebrating children birthdays, national days  will also  be called un Islamic. So my request is that we should not  make celebrations of birthday disputed if someone did not agree to celebrate he should not at least declare it un Islamic. After all these activities are arranged in the honour of Last messenger of ÀLLAH.

Comment: It is humbly requested that please text me where I have mentioned wrong reason for celebrating birthday of Holy Prophet PBUH. I want to correct myself. I have visited many  sites on stack exchange, negative rating is frequently given here. For my correction please text my errors..

Comment: your answer just puts your opinion forward. It does not even try to answer the three questions asked by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

No, its not a mandatory part of Islam to celebrate .

not proven by Qyran:

**If any verse of Book(Holy Quran) prove celebration of Hazrat Mohammad (s.a.w),then this became a law,practice,principle and constitution of Islam/Shariha**

and Sahaba also practice it .
Even not proven from any Sahaba , Tahbahien, Taba-tahbahien.

*Now,it look like cultural festival  but we can not change the law ,rules and regulation of Islam . not allow us to add any new thing in Islam (which pleasant for us )and remove from it (those fractious,tough,arduous,hard and painful for us).*

But remember  (***hyphen***):

12, Rabi-Ul-Awal is most precious/valuable/priceless day in the history of mankind. 
Main point is that not the celebration but problem and issues with complication of celebration method/way .

So if someone opponent to celebrate it ,doesn't mean that person is against of Hazrat Mohammad(s.a.w).Or those who celebrated in proper way (like individually recite Darood-0-salam/pray ) are not against of Islam.

Answer (score 0):

Islam is a religion of symbolism. e.g. our wudu is symbolification of the judgement day. Our hajj is a sybolification of many things that Prophet Ibrahim (PBUH) went through.

Is there anything wrong to make this day one of the many symbols of the prophet? A day that we use to be happy, and remind ourselves of his good deeds and his manners?

The year of his birth is also known as *عام الفیل* as in [the year of the elephant](https://www.google.com/search?q=the+year+of+the+elephant&oq=the+year+of+the+ele&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.3207j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Additionally it's not against Islam. It's just something we have nothing against it or supporting it.

All our eids are happy days. Are days where Satan is defeated. Isn't Satan defeated on the day of the birthday of the greatest of mankind?! Isn't that something worthy of happiness?

The general logic of the time of prophet it wasn't practiced is at fault, because that doesn't invalidate it. You could have new traditions added to Islam as long as:

- they don't add anything haram
- they don't remove anything halal

such celebrations break neither of the rules. Hence it's totally fine to do. The only thing that would make such celebration haram is to say that it's wajib thing to celebrate his birthday in such and such way. And to say that without doing such your committing haram.

Comment: How could you say that there is nothing against it. It is categorically prohibited as it comes under the category of innovation in religion.

Comment: @ForTheSakeOfAllaahAlone brother, did medical insurance, car insurance, banks, IRS (taxes), drones, organ donation, halal mortgage (I have not seen a halal mortgage company that doesn't penalize for delays, if you found one then please do introduce them to me, because I haven't been able to buy a house because I don't want to submit myself to such) Nor they give you the money without profit, etc exist? Yet you see many Muslims of both sects do use these and don't isolate themselves from the society.

Comment: @ForTheSakeOfAllaahAlone Islam is mute on a gazillion things and at the same time it isn't. If I came and said it's mandatory then yes it would be innovation. But I'm not saying that it's mandatory. I'm just doing this out of love. It makes me happy to celebrate his birthday. Gather some Muslim families around. Read of the Qur'an and the prophet's life.

Comment: It doesn't need to claimed mandatory for it to be an innovation, that is not how the sahaba understood it. There are hadith references of sahaba prohibiting innovations, without someone making it mandatory. I hope you would know, but if you want I'll find the hadiths for you.

Comment: And saying that Islam is mute about it is like saying Islam is mute about worshiping elephant god. Because there is no hadith or ayaah in Qur'an which mentions anything about worshiping elephant god. Does that mean it is allowed? No. It is categorically prohibited as it comes under the category of idol worship and shirk.

Similarly this comes under the category of innovation in religion.

Comment: @ForTheSakeOfAllaahAlone I'm just curious to what you think about this. If you're national team won in something in the Olympics, should Muslims of your country celebrate or act like nothing happened?

Answer (score 0):

Bismillahir Rahmanir Rahim. Alhamdulillahi rabbil-'alamin. Was-Salatu was-Salam 'ala Sayyidina wa Azimina, Wa Habibi Qulubina wa Shafii Nufusina, Abul Qasim Muhammad. Wa 'ala Ahli Bayti tayyibina tahireen.

---

`Is Eid-e-Milad-ul-Nabi (P.B.U.H) allowed or prohibited?`

It is neither allowed or prohibited.

But, according to the Quran the day Nabi Yahya AS was born and Nabi Isa AS was born is of significant kind. It is a blessed day.

> *— Saheeh International*
>
> **And peace be upon him (O Yahyâ (John the Baptist)) the day he was born**
> and the day he dies and the day he is raised alive.
>
> [Quran 19:15](https://quran.com/19/15)

> *— Saheeh International*
>
> And **peace is on me the day I was born** and the day I will die and the
> day I am raised alive.
>
> [Quran 19:33](https://quran.com/19/33)

If the day these Prophets were born Salaam is sent upon them and is blessed then definitely the day Muhammad SAW was born should also be blessed. So it seems that there is nothing wrong in celebrating birthday of Rasulullah SAW according to these verses.

Source: [13. The Martyr: John the Baptist (as) | Dr. Sayed Ammar Nakshawani](https://youtu.be/00JFRwrdvlE?t=2143)

The fact that our Christian brothers celebrate Christmas, the birth of Jesus, might have basis on these verses.

Answer (score 0):

If those who celebrate the birthday of the Prophet (ﷺ) eagerly defend this kind of act, how is it then that they can not provide any reference from the Quran or any Hadith that would support this?

If there would be any evidence that it was celebrated, then everybody would point to this or that narration, and proudly state that "it is to be found here, so we have a basis".

Since the Prophet (ﷺ) did not do it, and his companions never did it or knew about it, and even the four A'immah (Abu Hanifah, Malik, Shafi'i or Ahmad) never knew about it, how can we then celebrate it?

> Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said: "*If somebody innovates something which is not in harmony with the principles of our religion, that thing is rejected.*" Al-Bukhari ([2697](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:2697))

> The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: "[...] *Indeed, whomever among you lives, he will see much difference. Beware of the newly invented matters, for indeed they are astray. Whoever among you sees that, then he must stick to my Sunnah and the Sunnah of the rightly guided Khulafa', cling to it with the molars!*" Narrated in At-Tirmidhi ([2676](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:2676)) and Abu I'sa classed it Hasan Sahih; and in An-Nasa'i ([1578](https://sunnah.com/nasai:1578)): [...] "*Every newly-invented thing is an innovation and every innovation is going astray, and every going astray is in the Fire!*"

And that is why it is narrated in Al-Awliyah (7/26) that Sufyan at-Thawri (rh) said:

> 'Religious innovations are more beloved to Shaytan than sinful disobedience to Allah.'

Answer (score -1):

During the time of the Prophet it was clearly mentioned loads of times that birthdays are forbidden. Over the years there has been many misinterpretations of different hadiths and stuff like that so that's why people began to think it is compulsory to celebrate the Prophet's birthday.

The sahabas did not celebrate it and they just prayed for the Prophet p.b.u.h but they did this *all* the time not just on the day of his birth and death. It is perfectly fine to read and pray for the Prophet but not doing maniac stuff on his 'special' day. You only get sins for all that effort and if you just stay inside and pray you'll no doubt get ten times the amount of rewards than it's thought to be received by celebrating.

If someone doesn't attend this then they shouldn't be called a Satan, and in fact they should be *praised*.

Comment: Welcome to [islam.se]. Please go through the edits I've made and also try to provide references wherever possible.