# Milad, what does Quran, sahabha say it about

Tags: prophet-muhammad, source-identification, eid

There is much confusion on celebrating Milad-un-Nabi,i have a question posted [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/10580/is-eid-e-milad-ul-nabi-p-b-u-h-allowed-or-prohibited) (but it doesn't say much).While some say if you don't celebrate it (like lightning up house,masjids or don't take participation in it), your lost. You don't have love for prophet Muhammad (pbuh).Some say its own belief weather to celebrate it or not. All the festive going on in Masjid, the possessions going on to decorate building with lights etc. 
What does Quran, Hadith or sahaba says about it. I know there is a lot of logic answer, but it would be good if i can have a reference about it.

Comment: in Islam everything not Haram is Halal. so if there is no verse or hadith saying celebration is Haram so it is Halal.

Comment: @Ahmadi You missed *makrooh*.

Comment: @BleedingFingers yes thanks. in Islam anything not prohibited is permitted. this is a principal called Ibahah اباحه